# Ignore overlapping lines- beyond compare

Tags: java, beyondcompare4

I am using bc 4.4 to merge java files, I would like it to ignore overlapping lines like

```
file1:
Static String var1="this is example";
```

```
file2:
Static String var1=
"this is example";
```

Not sure this can be done, another alternative is to match the format of one file to another, but I could not figure it out.

Appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare 4.4.1 (current) can't compare across newlines.

```
one two
```

and

```
one
two
```

will always show as different.

Comparison across newlines is on the feature request list for a future version.

The only workaround is to to run files through a code beautifier to standardize the newlines before comparison.

Beyond Compare's Java source tidied file format (only available on Windows, but the same could be done on other platforms) runs files through [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) to standardize formatting before comparison.

Beyond Compare - [Additional File Formats](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4).